# Integration Test for WCF/SQL Server too slow?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wcf, integration-testing

I have an integration test that keeps failing (in Visual Studio), however, verifying the results by looking at the database indicate the system under test here is actually successful.

This is the basic idea of the test:

```
private static readonly EfContext db = new EfContext();

[TestMethod]
void Complete_System_Run_Through_Is_Successful()
{
    // Create a new unique message and request...
    var message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var request = new FooRequest { Message = message };

    var fooClient = null; /* WCF proxy */
    try
    {
        // Call the service...
        fooClient = new FooClient();
        fooClient.CallService(fooRequest);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close client or Abort faulted client...
        var channel = fooClient as ICommunicationObject;
        try
        {
            if (channel.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
                channel.Close();
        }
        catch { channel.Abort(); }
    }

    // Verify there are 15 instances (traces) present in the database...
    var actualNumberOfTraces = db.Traces.Count(x => x.Message == message);
    Assert.AreEqual(15, actualNumberOfTraces);
}
```

The WCF service being tested triggers a bunch of other downstream services (think 'service bus'), where each listening service adds an entry (a trace) to the database. From start to end, this process records 15 of these traces per complete system run through.

Verifying the results in the database indicate a successful test run (all 15 traces are present in the database). However the test run fails (in Visual Studio) with the actual number of traces found being between 3-6. The only thing I can come up with, is that the `Assert` is called too early (i.e. the database isn't finished being updated yet).

Anyway, everything is working correctly, all traces are indeed present in the database, I'm just having trouble with this test. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would have advised against the try{... } finally{} without a catch (containing Assert.Fail if thats whats required in cases of exceptions?) - or a using block for the wcf proxy ('fooclient'). is there anything you can move to your test start or test cleanup methods?

Comment: I've updated the code sample to include the close/abort logic. This is the preferred way of closing/aborting a WCF proxy, not a using statement. Basically, the try/finally block is there to handle closing/aborting, not exceptions.

Comment: I would put a catch block in the outer try also.

Comment: @Blam, agreed, *if* I was wanting to handle exceptions, which I don't since the client calls a *one way* operation. *Catching* exceptions from the first try block adds no value.

Comment: If fooClient = new FooClient(); or fooClient.CallService(fooRequest); throws an error you do not want to know?  You can still forward the exception.

Comment: How would you know what the details of that exception are when calling a one way operation? You won't, which is why the only thing you'll know is that the channel is faulted, which is why I handle that, and not an exception that will never be thrown to begin with. If fooClient = new FooClient() fails, it means the service reference/endpoint config/etc are out of whack, which is not what i'm testing here. my point is simply i know the client works, and any downstream exception will never be returned to the client, so why bother handle an exception that will never be thrown?

Comment: I can agree with you that in some scenarios, it would be desirable to catch exceptions opening the client, but that's not what i'm testing here. i would venture to say that catch block might provide value in production code, it just doesn't really add much value to this single test, other than to say the client configuration is broke

Comment: Easy dude.  Channel / client config broke adds no value for you.  Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an asynch method call.   This article describe WCF synch and asynch behavior.

[How to Call WCF Services Synchronously and Asynchronously](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91528/How-to-Call-WCF-Services-Synchronously-and-Asynchr)

Comment: It's async in that these services use MSMQ bindings/(one way  operations). Really, I'm just trying to figure out if this test will ever actually *pass*. I'm starting to think it won't, due to the nature of these disconnected services.

Comment: With asynch you should not expect it to pass so I just don't see how it adds any value.  I think you need a different approach to testing this.

Answer (score 0):

Well the ugly solution for the time being was to add a `Thread.Sleep(250)` to give the database time to catch up. If you can come up with a more elegant solution, I am absolutely interested in hearing it!

Comment: A far better method is to wait, and try the assertion several times in a loop for as long as you think sensible (say 30 seconds max).  Putting abitrary sleeps in the code makes the test non-deterministic and it will fail on different spec machines.

Comment: That's a great idea, could you post an example of how to do the Task[], WaitAll() calling the Assert in a loop like you're talking about? Just something quick to get me started?